# How do I parse the first n rows of a JSON String array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, ecmascript-6, pagination

I have a JSON string that is an array.

```
arrayString = "[
  { fName: 'John', lName: 'Doe'},
  { fName: 'Jane', lName: 'Doe'},
  { fName: 'Josh', lName: 'Doe'},
  { fName: 'Jack', lName: 'Doe'},
  { fName: 'Jill', lName: 'Doe'},
  { fName: 'Josh', lName: 'Doe'},
  { fName: 'Jean', lName: 'Doe'},
  { fName: 'Jake', lName: 'Doe'},
  { fName: 'Judy', lName: 'Doe'},
  { fName: 'Jery', lName: 'Doe'},
]";
```

Let's say this is an array of thousands of elements. If I parse this at once using .json(), it is going to take up a lot of memory. What I would like to do is parse only the first n rows that I need, like a client-side pagination where data is retrieved from a string. I have no control over how this huge amount of data is being passed from the server.

Comment: Take one of streaming parsing libraries, like https://github.com/jimhigson/oboe.js

Comment: have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-json

Comment: what have you tried already?

Comment: I am trying stream-json but there are not enough examples/docs for me to make it work. Not sure if that question should be on another post? @PranoySarkar

Comment: It seems like it's only for JSON files. not strings?

Answer (score 0):

This issue should really be dealt with server-side by the right design of an API, but you could also take a look at [range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests). Using them, you could request portion of the data, reject the last one that would most-probably get malformed and repeat. It ensures that client doesn't download and hold excessive amounts of data at once.

But if you want to stick to parsing portions of the whole dataset, which is already on the client machine, then that's a great use-case for generators from ES6 (ES2015):

```js
/**
 * Generator yielding a given number of records at a time.
 * @param {string} data          Data from which to extract.
 * @param {number} n             Number of objects per yield.
 * @yield {string} Array with the specified number of objects. Represented as
 *                 JSON-valid string.
 */
function* getNRecords(data, n) {
  let index = 0;
  while (index < data.length) {
    let result = data.substring(index).split('}', n).join('}');

    result = result.endsWith('}]') ? result : result + '}]';
    result = index > 0 ? '[' + result.trim() : result; // !result.startsWith('[') ?
    
    index += result.length;
    yield result;
  }
}

/* === EXAMPLE === */

const exampleData = '[{a: 1, b: 2}, {c: 3, d: 4}, {e: 5, f: 6}, {g: 7, h: 8}]';
const batchSize = 3;

for (let nRecords of getNRecords(exampleData, batchSize)) {
  console.log(nRecords); // TODO parse here
}
```

Taking up to N objects happens here: `data.substring(index).split('}', n).join('}');`.